# can we declare a variable in #define directive in c?

Tags: declaration, c-preprocessor

what would be the output for the following code snippet??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MUL(A,B) int t; t=A*B;
void main()
{
    int A=10,B=12;
    printf("%d", MUL(A,B));
}
```

will the output be an error(like declaration not allowed) or the given numbers would be multiplied???

Is the declaration allowed in #define preprocessor directive???

Comment: Did you test it yourself first? And to answer, it will cause an error. All you need is `#define MUL(A, B) A*B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler will replace your `printf("%d", MUL(A,B))` with `printf("%d", int t; t=A*B)`. It will cause an error *Type name is not allowed*, because you pass `int` typename in the `printf` function.
Yes, you can declare a variable using `#define`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MUL(A,B) int t; t=A*B;

void main()
{
    int A=10, B=12;
    MUL(A,B);
    printf("%d", t);
}
```

It will not cause an error. After `MUL(A,B)` you will be able to access `t` variable.
But declaring variables in this way is really complicated for understanding and debugging. Avoid it.